# Connection refused on express docker application

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I have a more complex application that I CURL against and receive this response to

```
http: error: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=3000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10ded04d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused')) while doing GET request to URL: http://localhost/
```

So I recreated a smaller example that shows the error.

```
app.use(createRouter());


const port = 3000;
http
  .createServer(app)
  .listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

createRouter looks like

```
export default function createRouter() {
  // *********
  // * SETUP *
  // *********
  const router = express.Router();

  /**
   * Uncached routes:
   * All routes that shouldn't be cached (i.e. non-static assets)
   * should have these headers to prevent 304 Unmodified cache
   * returns. This middleware applies it to all subsequently
   * defined routes.
   */
  router.get("/*", (req, res, next) => {
    res.set({
      "Last-Modified": new Date().toUTCString(),
      Expires: -1,
      "Cache-Control": "must-revalidate, private"
    });
    next();
  });

  // *****************
  // * API ENDPOINTS *
  // *****************

  router.all("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send({ message: "Welcome to Age Bold" });
  });

  // 404 route
  router.all("/*", (req, res, next) => {
    next(new ApplicationError("Not Found", NOT_FOUND));
  });
  router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err instanceof ApplicationError) {
      res.status(err.statusCode).send({
        message: err.message,
        data: err.data || {}
      });
      return;
    }
    res.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send({
      message: "Uncaught error"
    });
  });
  return router;
}
```

This is what my Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM node:8-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .
RUN npm install -g yarn
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NODE_ENV=local

CMD [ "node", "build/index.js" ]
```

I run it like this

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 <image-name>
```

As far as I can tell I'm doing everything I need to do to make this work.

This is how I make my curl request (using httpie)

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

the catch all route should return something, but instead I get the error.

I'm on MacOSX.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: are you sure that the continaer still running? what is the `dokcer logs NAME`result ?

Comment: does `docker ps` shows this container?

Comment: it does. I see the console log telling me that the app is listening on the port

Comment: One thing I did notice though is that when I open a new shell and run `docker ps` the container is not shown.

I need to run `eval $(minikube docker-env)`

I then run `docker ps` and it shows up

Comment: Can you take a shell of the container and curl your application from inside the container and see if it works?

Comment: @7_R3X it runs fine when curling from inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

ok this was pretty dumb.

I didn't know this about docker, but when you run

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

You are saying "Use Minikube's docker daemon". I didn't realize that Minikube's docker daemon was different from my host docker daemon, which meant that hitting localhost, meant hitting nothing.